# Best Ubuntu for laptop

Tags: toshiba-satellite

I have an old Toshiba Satellite, with  512 Mb of ram and a 1.6 GHz Celeron M, and 80 Gb Fujitsu hard drive.
What would be the best Ubuntu distribution to install on this laptop?  Or any other suggestions?  Upgrade the RAM to 2 Gb is an option maybe, 2Gb is the maximum supported. 
It's know it's getting old.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with the machine. My oldest used laptop is a 1.6ghz pentium-M with 1gb of ram & its *not fun* to use for some things, but for other things its great. Your main problem is ram; 2gb would be much better. Modern browsing does all the work on the browser (not on the server like long ago) so it needs memory.  Forget GNOME, KDE, even gtk3-MATE or Unity on 1gb or less; you're limited to XFCE or LXDE, openbox or lighter if you want a GUI. Does your CPU support PAE, if it doesn't you can't run any flash (not even on windows), but I'd choose Lubuntu & upgrade ram to 1gb+

Comment: if you install Ubuntu - you'll need to refer to this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE .   Note: this is not a problem with Ubuntu, but bugs in the intel celeron M processor you have (my pentium M too)

Answer (score 0):

Go with Lubuntu 14.04. It is supported till April 2019. I have 3G RAM on an old HP laptop with an AMD Turion T-58 processor. It's bit slow on Unity Desktop but still workable.

The RAM upgrade will increase responsiveness by reducing swapping memory to disk.

If you just need a server then it will work well.